# django-import-export import data from views.py

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm working on django-import-export library for importing & exporting xls format, Everything working probably at AdminModel,Now I'm trying to make importing working with views.py & templates but for some reasons didn't work with me

views.py

```
def simple_upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    person_resource = resources.SimsResource()
    dataset = Dataset()
    new_persons = request.FILES['myfile']

    imported_data = dataset.load(new_persons.read())
    result = person_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)  # Test the data import

    if not result.has_errors():
        person_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)  # Actually import now

    return render(request, 'import_sims.html', {'errors': result.has_errors(), 'result': result})

return render(request, 'import_sims.html')
```

resources.py

```
class SimsResource(resources.ModelResource):
class Meta:
    model = models.Sim
    fields = ['s_serial_number', 's_number', 's_provider', 'status']
```

forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

url.py

```
    url(r'^importing_sims/$', views.simple_upload, name='Import'),
```

template

```
    {% if errors %}
        errors:
        {{ errors }}
        <br><br><br>
        resluts :
        {{ result }}
    {% endif %}

      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="myfile">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
      </form>
```

and error output :

```
errors: True 
resluts : <import_export.results.Result object at 0x1072b75f8>
```

UPDATE :

after some updates in views.py here is the new error :

```
KeyError at /importing_sims/
'id'
```

which is not showing in admin import

and here is update :

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        file = form.cleaned_data['file']
        data = bytes()
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            data += chunk
        dataset = XLS().create_dataset(data)
        result = resources.SimsResource().import_data(dataset, dry_run=False, raise_errors=True, user=request.user)
        return render(request, 'import_sims.html', {'errors': result.has_errors(), 'result': result})

return render(request, 'import_sims.html')
```